# less -S not working

Tags: less, terminal-emulator, rxvt

I would like each line of a file to show up on just a single line in the terminal when viewing the file with `less`. `less -S` is not working for me, no matter how I try. With the flag `-S`, whether specified on the command line or in the program (entering `-S<CR>` in less), the line continues onto the line below, wrapped.

For a terminal emulator I am using `urxvt`, if that matters, with the following options:

```
rxvt-unicode (urxvt) v9.19 - released: 2013-10-27
options: perl,xft,styles,combining,blink,iso14755,unicode3,encodings=eu+vn+jp+jp-ext+kr+zh+zh-ext,fade,transparent, tint,pixbuf,XIM,frills,selectionscrolling, wheel,slipwheel,smart-resizecursorBlink,pointerBlank,scrollbars=plain+rxvt+NeXT+xterm
```

And this is in `.Xdefaults`:

```
URxvt.depth:                32
URxvt.geometry:             90x30
URxvt.transparent:          false
URxvt.fading:               0
URxvt.loginShell:           true
URxvt.saveLines:            50
URxvt.internalBorder:       3
URxvt.lineSpace:            -7

! Fonts
URxvt*font: xft:Monospace:pixelsize=20
URxvt*boldFont: xft:Monospace:pixelsize=20:style=bold
! Fix font space
URxvt*letterSpace: -1
```

Plus some other options for color scheme.

It's not working with `gnome-terminal`, either, so maybe it's not something having to do with `urxvt`.

Edit:

`less --version` gives `less 458 (GNU regular expressions)`.

Neither `$less` nor `$LESS` are set.

Comment: any environment variables interfering with your plans?  aliases?

Comment: What is the output of "echo $LESS" and of "less --version"?

Comment: Edited with this information.

Comment: Ah, my .bashrc was aliasing less with less -r, which must interfere with -S. Removing the alias fixed the problem.

Comment: @ammodramus Yes, you are correct.  https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/wordwrap-toggle-not-functioning-in-less-4175489153/

Answer (score 2):

Per mdpc's suggestion, I looked at aliases and found my .bashrc was aliasing `less` with `less -r` so that less can display colors. Removing this alias and thus removing the `-r` flag fixed the problem and made the `-S` flag produce the expected behavior.

From `man less`:

```
 -r or --raw-control-chars
          Causes "raw" control characters to be displayed.  The default is to display control characters using the caret  nota-
          tion;  for  example,  a control-A (octal 001) is displayed as "^A".  Warning: when the -r option is used, less cannot
          keep track of the actual appearance of the screen (since this depends on how the screen responds to each type of con-
          trol character).  Thus, various display problems may result, such as long lines being split in the wrong place.
```

So `-r` seems to break `-S`, understandably.

Comment: In order to retain displaying colors you should use the `-R` option instead of `-r`, which is compatible with `-S`.